# Inserting Sound In SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing on Android and I want to insert sound in SQLite with minimum storage.

Is there a simple example?

Comment: yes, the same as for images(and other binary files)....

Comment: This is not a code exchange site. Nor a tutorial site. You have to show your efforts in coding.

Comment: your are right but I taken more time  to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

Why would you need to store the audio files in a database? You can store the files in the assets folder and use then directly. You can also store the files in a sqlite BLOB column but this won't save any space.